# Unable to switch between giphy.trending and giphy.search

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, giphy

I have a chat application using NextJS and I'm trying to add a way to [send GIPHY images](https://developers.giphy.com/docs/sdk/#web).

I have things set up but I'm having trouble switching between the `giphy.search()` and `giphy.trending()` calls. Basically I have a component that displays the grid that contains the trending GIFs at that time. But above that grid, I have a text input where the user can search for specific GIFs. The value of this search input is stored in the parent component's state.

I initially tried having just one component for showing the grid (only trending):

```js
<Grid
  fetchGifs={(offset: number) => giphy.trending({ offset: offset, limit: 10 })}
  width={width}
  columns={2}
  gutter={8}
  onGifClick={onClick}
/>
```

Since that worked, I tried to add the ability to search:

```js
<Grid
  fetchGifs={
    (offset: number) => {
      if (searchTerm) {
        return giphy.search(searchTerm, { sort: 'relevant', lang: 'en', offset: offset, limit: 10 });
      } else {
        return giphy.trending({ offset: offset, limit: 10 });
      }
    }
  }
  width={width}
  columns={2}
  gutter={8}
  onGifClick={onClick}
/>
```

However, the SDK is erroring out. So I ended up making two separate components - one for the trending GIFs, and the other for a searchable GIFs:

```js
import { Grid } from '@giphy/react-components';
import { GiphyFetch } from '@giphy/js-fetch-api';
import Constants from '@/utilities/constants';
import { GIFFetcherProps } from '@/types';

const TrendingGIPHY = ({ width, onClick }: GIFFetcherProps) => {
  const giphy = new GiphyFetch(Constants.GIPHY_API_KEY);

  return (
    <Grid
      fetchGifs={(offset: number) => giphy.trending({ offset: offset, limit: 10 })}
      width={width}
      columns={2}
      gutter={8}
      onGifClick={onClick}
    />
  );
};

export default TrendingGIPHY;
```

```js
import { Grid } from '@giphy/react-components';
import { GiphyFetch } from '@giphy/js-fetch-api';
import Constants from '@/utilities/constants';
import { SearchGIFFetcherProps } from '@/types';

const SearchGIPHY = ({ searchTerm, width, onClick }: SearchGIFFetcherProps) => {
  const giphy = new GiphyFetch(Constants.GIPHY_API_KEY);

  return (
    <Grid
      fetchGifs={(offset: number) =>
        giphy.search(searchTerm, { sort: 'relevant', lang: 'en', offset: offset, limit: 10 })
      }
      width={width}
      columns={2}
      gutter={8}
      onGifClick={onClick}
    />
  );
};

export default SearchGIPHY;
```

And then on the parent component, I just determine which GIPHY component to render:

```js
{searchTerm ? (
  <SearchGIPHY
    searchTerm={searchTerm}
    width={width}
    onClick={handleGIFClick}
  />
) : (
  <TrendingGIPHY width={width} onClick={handleGIFClick} />
)}
```

This is somewhat working but not really. It's able to switch back and forth between the correct components based on the `searchTerm`. However, the searchable component only searches for the first letter. I'm out of ideas on how to implement this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find anything related to this approach anywhere, however, it seems like it uses some kind of technique to memoize the fetch so no unnecessary re-render and fetch will be done.

Fortunately, after digging more doc which led me to their Github pate, it has a runnable demo and it has the working example! https://github.com/Giphy/giphy-js/blob/master/packages/react-components/README.md#bare-bones-example

After reviewing their code, here's some thoughts

1. Your implementation is fundamentally done correctly
2. Turns out, Giphy really is doing some kind of memoization to their `Grid` component -- Their demo has a property for `Grid` component the your code doesn't have... which is `key`

In other words, you can solve the problem where only first letter is being parsed by adding it, like this --

```
<Grid
  key={searchTerm} // <-- HERE
  fetchGifs={(offset: number) =>
    giphy.search(searchTerm, { sort: 'relevant', lang: 'en', offset: offset, limit: 10 })
  }
  width={width}
  columns={2}
  gutter={8}
  onGifClick={onClick}
/>
```

(the demo has the prop `key` to be more complex, but you can make your own judgement)

```
key={`${channelSearch} ${term} ${activeChannel?.user.username}`}
```

Reference

- Grid component in their Github page: https://codesandbox.io/s/giphy-web-sdk-ssr-with-nextjs-irv19
- Official demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/giphy-web-sdk-ssr-with-nextjs-irv19
- A very simple working demo I made: https://codesandbox.io/s/giphy-react-components-forked-2myl9j?file=/src/index.tsx

Comment: Perfect! Thank you! This solved the issue of only searching for the first character.